# Change admin backend password minimum length

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, password, system-configuration

I set my frontend password minimum lenth to 6 from backend via

**Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Minimum Password Length**

But i can't find setting to manage backend admin password length from every configuration, i want to change backend admin password length to 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any of your module you need to override admin edit validation

You need to add the validation JavaScript to the edit user page in the admin, create a adminhtml_user_edit.xml layout file, and declare a template within the js `<referenceContainer>`

file `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_user_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="js">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="[module].adminhtml.user.password.js" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::user/password_js.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The password_js.phtml template file will add the JavaScript which will extend Magento’s validation class, and the custom validation method is added using the addMethod() method.

The example below shows adding validation of the password field that requires the password input to be at least 20 characters or more, containing alphabetic and numeric characters.

file: `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/templates/user/password_js.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            '[module]-validate-admin-password', function (v) {
                var pass;

                if (v === null) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Strip leading and trailing spaces
                pass = $.trim(v);

                if (pass.length === 0) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (!/[a-z]/i.test(v) || !/[0-9]/.test(v)) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (pass.length < 19) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            $.mage.__('Please enter 20 or more characters, using both numeric and alphabetic.')
        );
    });
</script>
```

As a `[module]-validate-admin-password` method has been defined, this needs to be added as a class to the password input field.

By default, the password field will have a validate-admin-password class, which will use the validate-admin-password method from validation.js.

As the password input fields are defined within a protected method in a Magento block class of the User module, the custom module will need to override this functionality.

To do this, add a `<preference>` within the custom module's di.xml file.

file: `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab\Main" />
</config>
```

Then add the [module]-validate-admin-password to the _addPasswordFields method.

file: `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/User/Edit/Tab/Main.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

class Main extends \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main
{
    /**
     * Add password input fields
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset $fieldset
     * @param string $passwordLabel
     * @param string $confirmationLabel
     * @param bool $isRequired
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _addPasswordFields(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset $fieldset,
        $passwordLabel,
        $confirmationLabel,
        $isRequired = false
    ) {
        $requiredFieldClass = $isRequired ? ' required-entry' : '';
        $fieldset->addField(
            'password',
            'password',
            [
                'name' => 'password',
                'label' => $passwordLabel,
                'id' => 'customer_pass',
                'title' => $passwordLabel,
                'class' => 'input-text [module]-validate-admin-password' . $requiredFieldClass,
                'required' => $isRequired
            ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'confirmation',
            'password',
            [
                'name' => 'password_confirmation',
                'label' => $confirmationLabel,
                'id' => 'confirmation',
                'title' => $confirmationLabel,
                'class' => 'input-text validate-cpassword' . $requiredFieldClass,
                'required' => $isRequired
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

after upgrade, dicompile, static deploy you should notice that the password input now uses the custom validation method.

Comment: is there any way to apply min length "4" for street address field for customer admin backend @Shoaib Munir

Comment: That would be a security risk :D I think in `password_js.phtml` file that I have listed in answer, you can define any length you need. you can check conditions in this file

Comment: There's a problem with this solution, the password confimation (the check that the password and confirm password input fields match) is getting the password value from class "validate-admin-password" which has now been changed. You'll get an error "Please make sure your passwords match.". To fix it you can add a custom validate-cpassword validator method in the same js file as above that checks your custom password field class.